# React focus div after it has loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, focus

I'm currently experimenting with React, and I've now run into an issue that I can't seem to solve.

In my application, I use a React library to handle hotkeys, these hotkeys have a scope, so when I want a certain set of hotkeys to be active in a div, I have to wrap that div with a `<HotKeys>` tag.

I have to toggle some of these divs, so I'll have something along the lines of

```
isActive ?
  <HotKeys ...>
    <div ...>...</div>
  </HotKeys>
  : <div ...>...</div>
```

I now need to figure out a way to focus the div when it's created. Pretty much every article on the web suggest something like this:

```
    const focusRef = useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        focusRef.current.focus()
    })

    return (
        isActive ?
            <HotKeys ...>
                <div ref={focusRef} tabIndex={-1} ...>...</div>
            </HotKeys>
            : <div ...>...</div>
    )
```

I've tried some variations, including having the div top level (without the `<HotKeys>` wrapping them), all to no avail.

When I print the focusRef object in the useEffect method, I do get the expected output, focusRef is correctly set and current is populated, but calling the focus method doesn't work. At one point I tried calling the focus method from a button and manually triggering it after the component had fully loaded, it seemed to work (`document.activeElement` was being changed), then for some reason it stopped working again. All this leads me to believe that somehow the component hasn't fully loaded, despite calling the useEffect hook, which, if I understand correctly, triggers when the element has rendered for the first time/after every change to state.

I'd really appreciate some help with this, since I basically started learning React yesterday.

Comment: What does your focus method look like?

Comment: @Dan that's a built-in method.

Comment: Well, you could just assign the div an id and use native javascript to focus it, ie ```document.getElementById('newdiv').focus()```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must to use an useCallback , because useRef don't notifies you when ref was created

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: This actually does seem to work with my original setup. As I said in my other comment, I've fixed the issue in a different way, but still thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to focus the div on load, certainly **useEffect** would be the correct hook with **useRef** where the ref is assigned to the div to focus. Moreover, that div must also have property **tabIndex=0**

But for some cases if somehow we don't have access to ref (Maybe using some third-party library or having our own custom component) then in order to do so in react we can make use of vanilla JS like so

```
;(document.getElementsByClassName('sort-dropdown-span-button')[0] as HTMLDivElement).focus()
```

**Note:** But that particular div must have class say **sort-dropdown-span-button** (like in above example) or id and property **tabIndex=0**

For more information on tabIndex - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex

Hope this will help you or somebody else in the future. Thanks!

Happy Coding :-)